# Need a batch/vbs to read a dash-separated txt file and output variable values

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Lets say i have a TXT file that includes only one line with multiple values separated with dashes, like this:

```
1000 -675 -76 -98 -10
```

What i need is to create a `batch` file or `vbs` that reads the `TXT` file and assigns each value a variable. The output should be like this:

```
variablename=1000

variablename=675

variablename=76

variablename=98

variablename=10
```

Is there any way to do this?? I appreciate any help....thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say "assigns each value a variable?"  Are you trying to set the environment, or variables in your program?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Each value on the TXT file should be assigned to a variable. Each variable should a have a particular name, for example:
apples=1000
pinapples=675

Comment: Apples do not fall from the sky! You can only have an array.

Comment: @Karsten  Where can we get the list of variable names?  Otherwise the variable names will have to be sequential. Var1, Var2, Var3, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to read multiple pieces of information in a .txt file from a batch file use a `for /f` loop:

```
set /p line=< Text file.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=-" %%a in ("%line%") do (
set var1=%%a
set var2=%%b
set var3=%%c
set var4=%%d
set var5=%%e
)
```

And so on. Note this will only parse the first line, (and you need to have some knowledge on how many numbers you are expecting). Tell me if you want a maluable script that can parse and amount of numbers.

Mona

Comment: Note that this solution will only work for up to 5 values in a line.

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you'd probably use a dictionary for storing the values:

```
Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vars = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

i = 1
For Each val In Split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll, " -")
  vars.Add "var" & i, Trim(val)
  i = i + 1
Next
```

If you want particular names for the dictionary elements you could provide them in an array:

```
Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vars = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

names = Array("apples", "pineapples", ...)

i = 0
For Each val In Split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll, " -")
  vars.Add names(i), Trim(val)
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Of course the number of names must be equal or greater than the number of values, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: +1 for the second approach (keys (or variable names) like var1, var2, ... are bad practice); but the .Split() should use a " -" separator.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the heads-up. As for the variable names: I agree that "numbered" variables are a terrible approach, but the OP didn't give us much to work with, so this was just for giving him a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a inc=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do (
   set a=%%i
   set a=!a:-=!
    for %%j in (!a!) do (
      set V[!inc!]=%%j
      set /a inc+=1
   )
)
for /l %%i in (0,1,%inc%-1) do echo !V[%%i]!
```

this will grab as many tokens as necessary.